# Replace variable value on a specific section of config file using bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have a config file that looks like this:

```
...
[env.staging]
name = "something"
...
[env.production]
name = "something"
...
```

I'm trying to replace the value of *name* on a specific environment using *regex* in the *sed* command in *bash*, but when I try to find the line by its section followed by a New Line, it doesn't work:

```
sed -i -e '/\[env\.production\]\nname =/s/=.*/= \"something_else\"/' config.toml
```

But the following command works fine, and of course, changes the *name* variable of both environments which is not desired.

```
sed -i -e '/name =/s/=.*/= \"something_else\"/' config.toml
```

Any ideas on how to achieve the correct result? (All my files are using LF line endings)

Comment: consider updating the question with more sample data that's indicative of your environment; eg, does the `name = "..."` entry always come immediately after the stanza/header? will you only be changing the `name = "..."` entry or could you need the ability to change other variables, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created some additional sample data for demonstration purposes:

```
$ cat config.toml
...
[env.staging]
id = 1
name = "something"
name2 = "something"
date = 2021/08/03
...
[env.production]
id = 2
name = "something"
name2 = "something"
date = 2022/01/23
...
[env.test]
id = 3
name = "something"
name2 = "something"
date = 2021/11/15
...
```

One `sed` idea using a range to find the desired section and then apply the change to said section:

```
$ sed '/\[env.production\]/,/^name = ".*$/ s/^name = ".*$/name = "something_else"/' config.toml
...
[env.staging]
id = 1
name = "something"
name2 = "something"
date = 2021/08/03
...
[env.production]
id = 2
name = "something_else"
name2 = "something"
date = 2022/01/23
...
[env.test]
id = 3
name = "something"
name2 = "something"
date = 2021/11/15
...
```

**NOTES:**

- we don't know what the rest of the config sections look like so I went a bit overboard by specifying the entire line (`^name = ".*$`)
- once OP is satisfied with the answer the `-i` option can be added to perform the 'in place' update of `config.toml`

Comment: Thank you as well ;) but I liked the other solution which has a shorter syntax.

Comment: it may have a shorter syntax but it does not answer your question of how to ensure only the `name = "..."` entry is modified; in fact, if `name = "..."` does not follow immediately after the stanza/header then you'll modify the wrong row, eg, run the other answer against my sample data; on the other hand, if you know you'll always be modifying the one row that immediately follows the stanza/header ... then the other answer is sufficient

Comment: So, your solution works regardless of where the variable is under that header? That's for sure more accurate then.

Comment: I just ran some tests and your solution is better in that regard, so I'll use yours instead. Thanks again.

Comment: yes, no, maybe ... really depends on what your **real** config file looks like and the various edits/changes you may need to make; this solution does not make any assumptions on where the `name = "..."` line occurs, but it **is** hardcoded for the `name = "..."` entry and the replacement value (`something_else`) ... both of which could be parameterized to use variables if needed; as Sundeep's pointed out, you may find a `toml`-specific tool provides better support, especially if you need to get a bit more complicated with the logic

Comment: My config file exactly looks like the sample, actually, it's a wrangler.toml from CloudFlare Workers. Your command works flawlessly as far as I tested. But of course, I can consider using other tools later, as for now, I don't want to make it too complex because I'm running this script on my GitLab Runner and prefer not to install extra tools on the server.

Comment: FYI you can preserve the whitespace at the start of the line (if any) by adding a whitespace capture group, i.e. `sed '/\[env.production\]/,/^name = ".*$/ s/^\(\s*\)name = ".*$/\1name = "something_else"/' config.toml`

Answer (score 2):

`sed` works line by line by default. You cannot match across multiple lines unless you use features to bring in multiple lines to the pattern space.

```sh
$ sed '/\[env\.production]/ {n; s/=.*/= "something_else"/}' config.toml
...
[env.staging]
name = "something"
...
[env.production]
name = "something_else"
...
```

`n` command will replace the pattern space with the next line. Use `N` when you need to process both lines together.

`{}` is used to group commands.

I would also suggest to use a `toml` tool like [dasel](https://github.com/TomWright/dasel) instead of `sed` for such cases.

Comment: and one more thing, how can I make sure it's the "name" variable I'm changing and nothing else. just in case...

Comment: you could use `name.*=.*` in the search term and use `name` in the replacement as well..

Comment: May you please give me an example? Besides, is this gonna work if the name variable is not on the first line after the header?